# Regex to get string till it hits a comma

Tags: regex

Let's say I have a string like this: `"1367,14,243,540"`(will always have 4 number and only numbers, no decimal places and always separated by comma)

How should the regex look like that would allow me to pick/filter out/return lets say `243` from the string?

Comment: you don't need a regex, use `.split(',');` it will return an array of the numbers as strings and you can parse them to ints in the process using `.map(function(){});` ,, if you insist try: `/\d+/g`

Comment: The regex is simple. The filtering and picking out bits are generally language-specific. Can you give more information, or a code example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is your regex if you insist on a regex `/\d+/g` (g here is for multiple selections in js, use matches with Microsoft framework) though you can use split (example using js):

```
var v='123,333,445,67';

console.log('split:');
console.log(v.split(',').map(function(n){return parseInt(n);}));

console.log('\nregex:');
console.log(v.match(/\d+/g).map(function(n){return parseInt(n);}));
```

**[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CME64/mw3YC/1/)**

the numbers will be returned in an array, you can use the index to access the desired one, let's say 2.

note: split is faster than regex, you can test the difference in performance using jsperf.com

**Edit:** For those who are interested in the performance difference, **[check this link](http://jsperf.com/regexesandsplit)**.

note2: map here is just for parsing the strings into integers, you can remove it if you want to keep them as strings.

Comment: Why do you specify a programmatic solution when the OP wanted a regex? What if the string changes, so that it has 10000 comma separated fields, is splitting still better then?

Comment: @Ingo split is always faster than regex, and I don't think regex will optimize space complexity more than it is in split. You also don't have to keep it in a variable if you want to save space, you can pick the selection with the index directly if it is only one selection that you desire as in the OP's question : `.split(',')[2];` ,, about the programmatic solution, I stated that it is an example to show how the regex will work using js language for the example nothing specific to the language, and split is in all languages, if not implemented manually (O(n) complexity).

Comment: In java, for example, split uses regex itself. Hence, "split is always faster than regex" is in itself nonsensical. Add to this that a regex that looks for information near the start of a string doesn't need to process all of the string, while split()-implementations usually do just that. (Again, in java, you can specify how many results you want, but this is another story.) I write this only to warn of spreading "as-we-all-know" type "wisdoms" too quickly.

Comment: @Ingo well then that case is specific to java. from what I understood from the OP's question is that he wants to pick a match as his selection later on, not using a fixed regex to do that for him. accordingly, the regex I provided still holds and can be associated with the condition of how many similar selections should precede it. split in the answer is a suggestion to replace the regex.

Comment: @Ingo check the edit part

Answer (score 1):

try

```
^([[:digit:]]+,){2}([[:digit:]]+)
```

your desired number is in capture group #2.

Comment: you don't have to consider the commas, just take the connected digits

Comment: @cme64: i don't quite understand your comment. the regex is destined as a single pattern to be applied to the test string without any further programming support apart from the regex engine.

Comment: @collapser you only need to select the connected digits, they will represent the numbers excluding the commas, you are trying to select numbers before and after commas, the less conditions you give to the regex the faster it will be executed.

Comment: @cme64: without the commas, the result data structure has to be built for each match in the test string and you have to reference the `n`th of these structures or iterate over the array. the regex is anchored and doesn't entail alternation or recursion, so its recognizer can be a plain simple state machine and the pattern can be matched or refuted by a single linear sweep of the test string (admittedly it depends on the optimization the regex engine performs  when constructing the recognizer).

Comment: @collapser that will be true if you are selecting a specific one match only, not multiple matches to use/(select from) them later.

Comment: @cme64: ok, i see, you're right - i have possibly misread the op's intent.

Comment: @collapser check the edit part in my answer for performance clearance :)

Comment: @cme64: +1 for performance test and advertising the web service.

Answer (score 1):

As one of the comments says, you shouldn't really use a regex in this case. Always try to use the appropriate tool for the job, and in this case the regex is HUGE overkill.

Your problem is solved easily as this

```
$sourceString = "1367,14,243,540";
$numbers = explode(",", $sourceString);
$neededNumber = $numbers[2];
```

Comment: You can't know if it is overkill, when the OP didn't state a language. In Java, for example, the explode (split) uses regex itself. This means, to split a string with 4 fields, it will invoke 4 regex matches that might very well be more expensive than 1.

Comment: We're all making assumptions here, since the OP didn't state the language. And in case with Java instead of writing regex you could still win in perfomance if you simply found the 2nd and 3rd commas in the string and simply extract the substring in between.

Comment: Just that, when I see half a page of indexOf() intermixed with corner case checks, string index checks, substring() etc. I scratch my head asking me "WTF did the author of this code want?", while when I see the below regex, I immediately see the structure of the string we're talking about, and when I then see a reference to group(2), I can tell instantly: Ok, he wants the 3rd numeric field. Is this less or more worth than some microseconds CPU time saved? To me, the answer is clear.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to describe your string:

```
^(\d+,){2}(\d+)
```

"From the start, number followed by comma appears two times, then another number."
You can pick the number of the second group, i.e. \2 or $2.

Comment: what did you add over collapser's solution other than changing the format of the digit ?

Comment: I didn't see his solution when I typed. In addition, my post tries to make the point that a regex is just a description of a string and you can translate from english to regex and back. Maybe it'll help OP later.